# asp.net c# Regular Expression Validator for formatted numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, format

I have a textbox with a numeric value. For example The number is 23542.56. The number is stored as double in an MySQL Database.

I convert the number to decimal and format it as string while I load the value from the database with thousands separator with ...ToString("N").

```
TextBox.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(mdr["Value"].ToString()).ToString("N");
```

My Regular Expression Validator accepts only digits and commas:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox" ValidationExpression="^\d+(\,\d+$)?$" ValidationGroup="NumericValidate">Allowed Chars are: 0-9 und ,</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The problem is that the Validator does not accept the formatted number, for exampel 23.542,56. What is a proper way to make him accept only "0-9 and ," but also accept the thousands separator?

Thanks in advance...

Info: To show "28542.56" as "23.542,56" is the common notation in germany, that is the reason why I format the number this way.

Comment: A regex question is hard to answer without *exact* input strings and expected outputs / behavior. What is the type of string that goes to the regex engine? `23542.56` or `23.542,56`? See [`^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*)(?:[,.]\d+)?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%7c%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%28%3f%3a%5b.%2c%5d%5cd%7b3%7d%29*%29%28%3f%3a%5b%2c.%5d%5cd%2b%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=23542.56%0d%0a23.542%2c56&o=m).

Comment: Thank you very much - that pattern was exacty what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape the comma `,` but you have to escape the dot `.`, otherwise it will match every character, as in `.*`, which matches everything.

The `[` square brackets `]` match *any character in the given class*, which contains dot `.`, comma `,` and digits.

If you want to be more strict and have triplets and such you must do:

```
  thousands v          v literal comma
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d*)?$
         ^           ^ non-capturing-groups
```

This will still match ill-formed numbers with leading zeroes `0` such as:

```
00
01
003.999,99
```

There's a very easy way to exclude those, too. I leave it to you as homework :)
Hint: `[1-9]`

---

**EDIT:** accept only 1 1,11 1.111 1.111,11 1111,11

The regex for this should be:

```
^1+(?:\.111)*(?:,11)?$
```

It may be a little different for some corner cases, but that's basically it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: Is there a way that the validation accepts those inputs:

    1
    1,11
    1.111
    1.111,11
    1111,11

Comment: Thank you very much